# I need a hart to be half way red from bottom and half way white at top but not a gradual color chance. In side a black circle

Tags: html, css

I need this hart to be half way red and half way white inside a solid black circle and also the color chance cant be gradual. I have been using linear gradient for colors but cant seem to get it just right also as soon as i add the black circle as back ground then the code goes up in flames.

```css
.heart-shape{
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: red;
}
.heart-shape:before,
.heart-shape:after{
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  content: '';
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(135deg,white ,white 20%,red 10px,red 25%);
}
#rcorners {
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: black;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
.heart-shape:before{
  bottom: 0px;
  left: -100px;
}
.heart-shape:after{
  top: -100px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<div  style="display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;" class="heart-shape"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Frankly no-one makes shapes this way anymore, use an SVG it's much simpler and responsive.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67917454/html-css-fill-a-svg-but-only-50-height